# Creating a macro which runs from the last row from which it was closed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro which finds the column and copies the column values under it. The column indexing is provided through which the macro finds the column in another sheet. The macro runs fine when I run it the first time but the second time when I rerun the macro I want the macro to exclude the columns which I have done the first time and do the same thing again.
The code is given below:

```
For i = 2 to 18 Step 2 'i is the the column index from which it will paste the info in the next sheet according to the column index
 For j = 3 to 39 'j is the rows
  Windows("Tracker Macro.xlsm").Activate
  ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
  Worksheets("Allowance").Activate
  x = Cells(j,i).Value
  y = Cells(1,i).Value
  wb.Activate
  ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
  LR = Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row
  LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  Range(Cells(2,1), Cells(LR, LC)).AutoFilter Field:x, Criteria1:="="
   For Each Cell In Range(Cells(3, x), Cells(LR, x)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    wb.Activate
    s = Cell.Row + 2
     If s <> 4 then
      wb1.Activate
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
      Cells(s,y) = "x"
     End If
   Next Cell
 ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
 Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Something is missing from this macro - what is `i` and where is it instantiated or declared?

Comment: FYI your missing the `.` before `End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: `wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(s,y).Value = "x"` you can cut out all of your select/activate here...